# A condition for a function to be complete measurable

Tags: real-analysis, integration, measure-theory, limits

I was doing this exercise in Real Analysis of Folland, but got stuck on this problem. I get no clue about how to define these 2 sequences of functions, so I hope someone can help me to solve this. I really appreciate.

> > Let $(X, M, \mu)$ be a measure space with $\mu(X) < \infty$, and let $(X, \overline{M}, \overline{\mu})$ be its completion. Suppose $f: X \rightarrow R$ is bounded. Then $f$ is $\overline{M}$-measurable iff there exist sequences $\{\phi_{n}\}$ and $\{\psi_{n}\}$ of $M$-measurable simple functions such that $\phi_{n} \le f \le \psi_{n}$ and $\int(\psi_{n} - \phi_{n})d \mu \lt n^{-1}$. In this case, $\lim \int{\phi_{n} d \mu} = \lim \int{\psi_{n} d \mu} = \lim \int{f d \overline{\mu}}$

Thanks so much all for your help.